# SQL is updating a record thread safe

Tags: sql, sql-update, thread-safety

I am working on a server that accesses a database. It is possible for multiple people to access the same record. Will each request wait in line, or will they all try to modify that record at the same time.

Example:
I have an image, and the database will keep track of how many "likes" that image has.

```
UPDATE `images` SET `image_likes` = `image_likes` + 1 WHERE `image_id` = 0;
```

Assuming that specific image has 0 "likes" and 3 people at the same time "like" that image, would those 3 request properly be processed, resulting in that image having 3 likes, or is there a chance that the record can be corrupted, or at the very least be incorrect, maybe only showing 2 "likes"?

My Database uses the MyISAM engine and I am using it through GoDaddy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php by itself is not thread safe but MySQL is , in this case MySQL will handle this issue and you will get 3 likes. Unless there is any other operation involved this should not be a problem

You can give it a try by calling that script via console multiple times to see what happens